# Copy table when type a text to cell

Tags: excel

I have excel table form.

I need to setup when somebody type text to last cell so excel will automatically copy whole table to new list for continuing in filling next data into new list.

Sorry, but I'm beginner with Excel. I probably need to setup "IF" statement which start macro which copy the table to new list. But I don't know how to do it.

Thanks in advance for every tip and advice

Comment: Any text or something specific like RUN_THIS ? What cell in Excel?

Answer (score 1):

This macro checks to see if `A30` is `RUN_THIS` and if it is it copies `A1`  through `A29` to the area starting at `B1`.  If you want any of these to be different, you will have to modify the script.   To Create a macro, Right-click on the Sheet name (`Sheet1`) at the bottom of the spreadsheet and select `View Code`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("A30:A30")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

    ' This will check to see if cell A30 is equal to RUN_THIS and  It then
    ' copies the values from A1 through A29 to the space starting at B1

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A30").Select

    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A30").Value = "RUN_THIS" Then
        Range("A1:A29").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("B1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Range("D15").Select
    End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @user2166133 If you found this acceptable please click on the large downward facing arrow to Accept this. Clicking on the up arrow does not indicate that you have Accepted it. Thanks!

Comment: @user2166133 please click on the large downward facing arrow to "Accept" this. Clicking on the up arrow does not indicate that you have Accepted it. Thanks!